# How to add RDLC Report in ASP.NET Project?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, rdlc

I am trying to generate RDLC Report. After couple of steps done when I click 'Add' -> 'new item' -> it was supposed to generate a option for Add Report. But that report option is not generating.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you install [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001) ??
2. After install `Microsoft RDLC Report Designer` open Visual Studio right click on Project then click 'Add' -> 'new item' -> right top search box input `report` you will find rdlc.

Comment: is Microsoft RDLC Report Designer any good? i`ve been reading some bad reviews